# Spring call Jndi variable to jsp

Tags: java, spring

I have some difficulties to call a JNDI variable to my jsp Page.

Context.xml :

```xml
<!-- Environnement de l'application -->
<Environment name="app/env" override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="Développement" />
```

conf-view-spring.xml

```xml
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiLookEnv" jndi-name="app/env"
    expected-type="java.lang.String" />
```

footer.jsp

```
<div class="panel-footer footerstick clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <strong><c:out value="${jndiLookEnv}"></c:out></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no error but my jndiLookEnv is empty, 
What's wrong in this case?
Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth that contraption? The `jnidLookEnv` is already a `String` why create another one with that value. Just remove the `jndiEnv` one and either rename the JNDI one or use `${jndiLookEnv}` in your page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , i have update my code in the topic , but a have the same problem :) my jndiLookEnv return an empty value

Comment: Well of course it wil always be, if you don't expose the bean to your JSP it will not work. You currently have a bean in your context but that isn't accessible by the JSP. You will need to add it to the model of your page (which are basically request attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beans in the context aren't accessible by the JSP (or at least not in the way you are trying to). You would need a scriptlet to get access to the `ApplicationContext` and do a `getBean` to retrieve the value. Using `${jndiLookEnv}` isn't going to work.

To make it available for easy use in the JSP you need to add a `ServletContextAttributeExporter` to expose it.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.suppor.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="env" value-ref="jndiLookEnv" />
        </map>
    </properties>
</bean>
```

Now you can use `${env}` to reference to value.

Now you can improve on this and remove the JNDI lookup al together (assuming that you are on a recent spring version).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.suppor.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="env" value="#{environment['app/env']}" />
        </map>
    </properties>
</bean>
```

The `Environment` abstraction will do a lookup for the property in various locations, one of them being JNDI (you could override the `app/env` property using properties or a system property for instance.